# Save table with Japanese to CSV in R

Tags: r, csv, cjk

I import a table from SQL server to R with Japanese characters. It shows normally in R. But when I try to save the table to csv file and open it in excel, the Japanese characters are not showing at all. Instead it only shows things like "<U+30CF><U+30F3><U+30C9><U+30AC><U+30F3> <U+30DB><U+30EB><U+30B9><U+30BF><U+30FC>". I have installed Japanese input in my computer and if I just input Japanese into a new excel sheet it will show normally. My excel version is 2019, R version is the newest. I wonder what I can do in R to save Japanese characters to csv without error? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the code that you used to save to csv from R.

Comment: write.csv(lowclick, "C:\\Users\\Stella\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Amazon ads\\lowclick.csv")

Comment: The first thing to try is `write.csv(lowclick, "C:\\Users\\Stella\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Amazon ads\\lowclick.csv",  fileEncoding='UTF-8')`

Comment: Hi I just tried and it shows the same problem. I also tried to open in excel by importing csv data and choose encoding to UTF-8 but still no luck.

Comment: Next thing to try:  Before writing the file,  run `Encoding(lowclick$ColumnWithJapaneseCharacters, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: Got an error message saying "Error in Encoding(validclick$KeywordText, "UTF-8") : 
  unused argument ("UTF-8")"

Comment: Doh.   My error.  Should have been: `Encoding(lowclick$ColumnWithJapaneseCharacters) = 'UTF-8'`

Comment: I tried Encoding(validclick$KeywordText) = "UTF-8" and write.csv(validclick, "C:\\Users\\Stella\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\validclick.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8") but still the Japanese characters don't show.

Comment: Sorry.  Out of ideas.